# Unable to load Sphinx.so dynamic library after PHP upgrade

Tags: php, sphinx, pecl

I am upgrade PHP to 5.4.4.1 on my debian server.
I have some modules from PECL, and now one of them shows:

```
#php --ini
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/sphinx.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/sphinx.so: undefined symbol: sphinx_open in Unknown on line 0
```

reinstall form PECL don't resolve problem, what can I do?

Comment: A symbol is not defined. Ensure all definitions are available when you compile the extension. You probably have a version mismatch. PECL sphinx is here: http://pecl.php.net/package/sphinx

Comment: Which version of the *sphinxclient* library have you installed on your system?

Comment: i reinstall sphinxclient lib, and now its works:-) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly just uninstall the extension. Its not worth the bother.

Just include sphinxapi.php in your scripts instead.

The pure PHP version actully performs better than the extension, and is in sync with the server - so can do all the latest features, and contact the latest version of sphinx correctly.